# SSL Certificates location in Kafka trigger Azure Functions

Tags: java, azure, apache-kafka, azure-functions, spring-kafka

I am developing kafka trigger based azure functions in JAVA where the function uses below configuration for connection:

```
@KafkaTrigger(name = "kafkatrigger", topic = "kafka.topic", brokerList = "%BrokerList%",
                    consumerGroup = "default-consumer", protocol = BrokerProtocol.SSL,
                    sslCertificateLocation = "%sslCertificateLocation%", sslCaLocation = "%sslCaLocation%",
                    sslKeyLocation = "%sslKeyLocation%", sslKeyPassword = "%keyStorePassword%",
                    cardinality = Cardinality.ONE, dataType = "string")
```

So, In above configuration I do not want to upload the `client private key, client public key and ca certificate` through artifact on the container for security purpose. So, I want to keep the certificates at secure location like `key vault, secret management` and use their reference location in @KafkaTrigger annotation. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You'd seen some pre-initialization function or an external Spring library that downloads the values from Azure. Spring-kafka alone doesn't do this. Otherwise, Azure functions would maybe pass them through environment variables but you still need to download files.

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, Thanks for the suggestion but we can not use spring library because spring container will start after the function is triggered. I will check any pre initialization function functionality.

Comment: You have full control over when Kafka containers get started.

Comment: You might want to see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault

Comment: Yeah..but to start kafka itself I need the certificate properties in @Kafkatrigger iannotation..so If connection to kafka is possible then the function will get triggered and the function will invoke spring app.

Comment: Once spring app started we have full control to keyvault but it will start only after the successful connection with kafka.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250993/discussion-between-nilesh-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: I dont use Azure. I'm just saying you need to connect to the key vault before you even attempt to connect to Kafka (start the trigger as disabled) since you are requiring secrets to be injected into your app. You would then use SPEL expressions with `${someSecret}` syntax, not `%value%`